# Uncommon question with "Ethical hacking" challenge

Tags: java, github, gitlab

I have a rather unusual question, but I still don't understand much in programming to understand if it is possible to do what I want. So I feel like I need a little story. My name is Nick, I live in Ukraine and am currently studying as a student in one of the IT firms. Now is the middle of my studies and, if everything goes good, they will give me a chance to get a job in 2 months. But not only me, but 300 more students from all over the country, since the training is online, and the company in which we will get one of the largest in the CIS.
This is where I come closer to the task. To complete the course, we have to complete 8 practical sessions with 5-6 tasks in each. Upon their implementation, we upload the code to the git lab. For this, the company has opened an account for each of us. Then the electronic program for checking assignments - E-Mentor compiles our code, provides input data to fill each class and checks the task. In case of an error, it creates log, which often does not provide complete information. Since some of the test data is always hidden. At the end, the program sets progress points for us. And we all want to get 100%)

```
**Task: Get input data from the E-Mentor server in the form of a file and automatically push it from the server side to my Git Lab account.**
```

I am not asking for the complete code, but I am asking you to help me write pseudo code so that I can implement it in full.
I represent it like this:

1. The server clones my code
2. Compiles it
3. Runs tests
4. At this time, a file is created that copies all incoming information from tests
5. Somehow the created file is being pushed to my gitlab
   For example:
   GitBash is started on the server and logs into the gitlab under my login. In this case, it is restricted to rewrite the password and login used by the server itself, as it will be immediately noticed.
   This is the coolest challenge that I want to try to do and share it with all students)

Comment: I would ask for clarification from the company in writing. Hacking is against the law in many countries.

Comment: This sounds like a typical CICD workflow.  The first step is to get the compilation to work successfully locally.  Once you have it working locally without this build pipeline involved, reach out to the instructor for clarification on a specific question.

Comment: Hey guys, this isn't all that serious. This is a free training program that aims to find talented candidates. And in fact, I just want to see what tests the program conducts on my own code! Moreover, I will share all of this with the entire student community at once, so it's all pretty open.and does not affect the law.